# Combined table sql query

Tags: sql

I have a JavaScript program where if you type in 'let's talk' or something similar it goes to its question function where it asks users questions from a table of questions. It only asks questions haven't been asked.

I have set up 3 tables.

```
(questions)            (people)                (questionasked)
QID  Question           PID   Person           QID PID  Asked   Answer   

1   What is life?        1  Lindsay           1     1   N       ''.
2   Do you know Kate J?  2  Kate              2     1   Y       'Yes, Kate is cool'.
```

For the table questionasked there is a combined primary key of QID and PID so the same question is not asked twice.

What is a good way to get the question to be asked. The table of questions could have 20+ questions in it. 
The variable given to the php file making the query is just the name: name (name of user).
eg.

```
$query1 = "SELECT q.Question 
FROM questions q inner join questionsasked qa 
ON q.QID = qa.QID 
WHERE qa.Asked='N'";
```

can I add another AND clause here to check

```
     questionsasked inner join people on PID = people.PID AND people.Person = $name  ?
```

The above query doesn't return anything.. still need more practice with SQL.. I would like it to return the first question in the result.

OK I got an answer to this mostly to vidyadhar's answer, and also combined 'OR qa.Asked IS NULL' from JW which was a good point as I may not fill out the 'questionsasked' table unless the question was actually asked. It may be best just to have a table of questions, then as the questions are answered fill out the questionsasked table.

The answer I am using is:

```
 $query1 = "SELECT q.Question 
 FROM questions q
 INNER JOIN questionsasked qa 
 ON q.QID = qa.QID 
 INNER JOIN peopleiknow p
 ON qa.PID = p.PID
 WHERE qa.Asked='N' OR qa.Asked IS NULL
 AND p.Person = '$name'";
```

Any further tweaks are welcome.

Actually I still had problems with this, so modified the table, and question and showed the php code in this question: [SQL query in PHP file in need of a fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277245/sql-query-in-php-file-in-need-of-a-fix)

Comment: do you want to get the list of questions where the user didn't aswer the question?

Comment: I'd like to get the next question that the user hasn't answered. So if last time the user answered 2 questions it would ask the 3rd question.

Comment: Your query isn't even valid SQL, aren't you getting an error? You can't reference a table `questionasked` that isn't in the `FROM` or `JOIN` clause. Also, when you use backticks, you wrap them around the tablename and column name separately, not together.

Comment: ok, I fixed up a query that output a question, however I am still looking to make this user specific. Taking in the variable $person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this will work

SELECT
q.Question
FROM questions q inner join questionasked qa
ON q.QID=qa.qid
WHERE qa.asked='N'

Comment: I got a result from this (below)  however I need to not only get a question that hasn't been asked yet, it needs to be user specific, so needs to get the question that hasn't been asked by the user that is to be fed into the query.                                     $query1 = "SELECT q.Question 
 FROM questions q inner join questionsasked qa 
 ON q.QID = qa.qid 
 WHERE qa.asked='N'";

Comment: I added your edit to the original question, as I at least I got an answer from your query.

Comment: yes you can add it.... in accordance with inner join you can add it any where ( on / where clause ) but careful when using outer join some time you should add it in on clause to satisfy join condition

Comment: Ok could get an answer with this. I did another inner join:          INNER JOIN people p ON qa.PID = p.PID and added AND p.Person = '$name' in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.PID, f.Person,
        d.question
FROM
        (
            SELECT  a.PID, b.QID
            FROM    people a, questions b
        ) c 
        INNER JOIN questions d
            ON c.QID = d.QID
        INNER JOIN people f
            ON c.PID = f.PID
        LEFT JOIN questionasked e
            ON  c.QID = e.QID AND
                c.PID = e.PID
WHERE   e.Asked = 'N' OR e.Asked IS NULL
```

Comment: Does this take into account the user? As I would like to feed into the query the username and get out a question that hasn't been asked to that user. I can't see a variable being fed into the query besides 'N'

Comment: the result of the query above will list all question that has not been ask to the user, if you want for a specific user, use this where clause `WHERE   (e.Asked = 'N' OR e.Asked IS NULL) AND f.Person = 'nameHere'`

Comment: This is potentially the right answer too.. but I will reword my question and put a link to the question at the bottom of this question. As I have slightly changed my table structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN in this case. Please check

```
SELECT Q.Question
FROM questions Q INNER JOIN questionasked A ON Q.QID=A.QID
    INNER JOIN people P ON A.PID=P.PID
WHERE A.QID= 'Question ID' AND
    A.PID='Person ID' AND
    A.Asked='Y'
```

Comment: Does this take in two variables 'Question ID' and 'Person ID' from the user? I was looking to just feed in the user name.

Comment: the people table (P) only has PID and Person (first name) so I'm not sure why you put P.QID in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Yes, u can pass variable or static value like 1, 2 etc for 'Question ID' and 'Person ID', and please check the edited answer for the issue P.ID(It came by mistake).

Answer (score 0):

i assume this problem should be solved if you have a look at you PHP question having more or less the same topic.

Greetings

Martin